# "split" not working when the pattern matches the first line in the file

Tags: perl, split

I'm processing files, looking for text like one of the following:

- `module mymodule (`
- `module mymodule(`
- `module mymodule`

The `(` may or may not be on the same line. There are other variations, but let's suppose it's one of the three shown above.

I slurp the file into `$verilog_model` and perform the split

```
$barename = 'mymodule';

my $verilog_model = do { local $/; <VIF> };
close VIF;

($head, $body) = split /module\s+$barename[\050]/, $verilog_model, 2;
$extra = '(';

if ( $head eq '' ||  $body eq '') {
    ($head, $body) = split /module\s+$barename\s+\050/,  $verilog_model, 2;
    $extra = '(';
}

if ( $head eq '' ||  $body eq '') {
    ($head, $body) = split /module\s+$barename/,  $verilog_model, 2;
    $extra = '';
}
```

None of these `split` calls worked when `module` was the first line of the file, but when I added a space as the first line then `split` was able to find the module and I got what I wanted for `$head` and `$body`.

Why is it that `split` is not able to find `module mymodule` when it's the first line of the file?

Comment: [Verilog on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Verilog)

Comment: What do you expect to appear in $head and $body? If the very first line starts with `module`, $head must be empty, as nothing precedes the first match of the pattern given to `split`.

Comment: Of course! When module is the first line of file starting at column 1 then head will be empty, I figured it had to be something obvious, duh on my part. Thanks everyone for your responses! --Ross

Answer (score 1):

> None of these splits worked when module was the first line of the file

It's hard to comment on this as you don't explain what you would see if the split worked as you expected.

I think you might be misunderstanding what [`split()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) does. The regex that you pass to `split()` is used as the separator between two elements in the split list. Therefore, if the regex matches at the very start of your string, then the first element in the list returned must be empty.

You are doing the equivalent of this:

```
my $string = "\tSome data";
my ($head, $body) = split /\t/, $string;
```

In this situation, `$head` will be empty and `$body` will contain "Some data".

If this doesn't explain what you are seeing, then please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40142169/edit) to clarify what you want to see and what you are actually seeing.